# How to check if an array index is a hole/empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried to check for `null` values in arrays and it didn't work. I discovered I haven't got any `null` values but empty ones.
[image]
How do I check if values are empty?

```
if(array[i] === null) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`empty x 5` means that you have 5 undefined values in your array. In javascript `undefined` and `null` are two different concepts [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null)

to check for null values just use `if(arr[i]===null){}`

Note that `0,false,null,undefined,""` all are considered as falsy values.So if you simply use

```
if(arr[i]){//do something}
else {//do another thing}`
```

for above mentioned values then `if` block will never be executed.
Example

```js
let falsyValues=[0,false,null,undefined,""]

falsyValues.map((val,i)=>{
if(falsyValues[i])
console.log("executing if block with ",val)
else
console.log("else bock executed with ",val)
})
```

To only check for `null` values you have to specifically look at the value.

```js
let arr=[1,undefined,3,undefined,null,6,null,8,null]

arr.map((val,i)=>{
if(arr[i]===null)
console.log("null value found at index ",i)
else if(arr[i]===undefined)
console.log("undefined value found at index ",i)
})
```

Comment: The holes in arrays are not `null` or `falsy`, it doesn't seem the question is about those. It's about detecting whether an index is a hole or not.

Answer (score 3):

If the index is not a key of the array, then it is an empty element. Checking for null or undefined will not work, as they are possible values.

```
if(!array.hasOwnProperty(i)) //element is empty
```

```js
let array = [1,2,3,undefined,null,0,,,,];//3 empty slots
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  if(!array.hasOwnProperty(i)){
    console.log("empty");
  } else {
    console.log(array[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know that your array contains `empty`/`null`/`undefined` values or not. Then you can simply achieve that by using [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

Demo **:**

```js
var arr1 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, '', '', '', '', ''];

console.log(arr1.some(item => !item)); // true

var arr2 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

console.log(arr2.some(item => !item)); // false
```

If you also want to know the index of empty values. Then you can iterate over an array by using [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and print the index of empty values.

Demo **:**

```js
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, '', '', '', '', ''];

arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (!item) {
    console.log(index);
  }
});
```